# Get href real value with selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, canonical-link

I have to check the page's canonical tag, but I have a problem when the href is empty.
This is the code:

```
ChromeOptions chromeCapabilities = new ChromeOptions();
chromeCapabilities.AddArguments("disable-infobars");
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeCapabilities);
webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com/subpage/page");

List <IWebElement> linkElements = webDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("link")).ToList();
string canonicalHref = linkElements.Find(x => String.Compare(x.GetAttribute("rel"), "canonical") == 0).GetAttribute("href");

//debug
var html = linkElements.Find(x => String.Compare(x.GetAttribute("rel"), "canonical") == 0);
Console.WriteLine(html.GetAttribute("outerHTML")); //<link href="" rel="canonical" />
Console.WriteLine(html.GetAttribute("href")); // should be "" but I get https://www.example.com/subpage/page
Console.WriteLine(html.GetAttribute("rel")); //canonical       

Console.WriteLine(canonicalHref); // should be "" but I get https://www.example.com/subpage/page
```

Wrong settings example:

[image]

And I get the URL not empty string... but why? Did I call the wrong attribute? Any idea to get the real value?

Answer (score 1):

The method `GetAttribute` returns the DOM property if it's present or the HTML attribute if the property is missing. It looks like the page changed the property.

To get the HTML attribute, you'll have to use a script injection:

```
string href = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(
    "return arguments[0].getAttribute('href') || '';",
    link)
```